# Is there an equivalent to numpy.digitize that works on an pandas.IntervalIndex?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I need to match each hour of the month to a monthly total for the month that the hour falls in.

I am passed a DataFrame (`monthly_totals`) with a time-based `pandas.IntervalIndex`, and a second DataFrame (`hours`) with a `pandas.DatetimeIndex`. More generally, I need to match the index of one DataFrame, to the interval of another DataFrame that each entry falls into.

I have a working solution, using `pandas.Series.apply`, but it is quite slow. I see that [numpy.digitize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) exists, and it taunts me, because the `bins` parameter must be an array, not an IntervalIndex.

My first attempt, which works, but takes about 1 second to process a DataFrame of length 8760, is as follows:

```py
def get_mock_montly_totals(self):
    start = '2018-07-01'
    end = '2019-07-01'
    hourly_rng = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='H')
    monthly_rng = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='MS')
    mock_series = pd.Series(1, index=hourly_rng)
    bins = (monthly_rng + pd.offsets.Day(pd.Timestamp(start).day - 1))
    cuts = pd.cut(mock_series.index, bins, right=False)
    groups = mock_series.groupby(cuts)
    monthly_totals = groups.sum()
    return monthly_totals

def get_interval_value(self, frame, key):
    try:
        return frame.iloc[frame.index.get_loc(key)]
    except KeyError:
        return np.nan

result = api.get_secret_data().resample('H').asfreq()
hours = result.index.to_series()
monthly_totals = self.get_mock_montly_totals()

# This line takes over a second to run, which is too slow.
result['monthly_totals'] = hours.apply(
    lambda h: self.get_interval_value(monthly_totals, h))
```

Where `monthly_totals` looks like:

```
[2018-07-01, 2018-08-01)    744
[2018-08-01, 2018-09-01)    744
[2018-09-01, 2018-10-01)    720
[2018-10-01, 2018-11-01)    744
[2018-11-01, 2018-12-01)    720
[2018-12-01, 2019-01-01)    744
[2019-01-01, 2019-02-01)    744
[2019-02-01, 2019-03-01)    672
[2019-03-01, 2019-04-01)    744
[2019-04-01, 2019-05-01)    720
[2019-05-01, 2019-06-01)    744
[2019-06-01, 2019-07-01)    720
dtype: int64
```

`hours` looks like:

```
time
2018-06-27 00:00:00-10:00   2018-06-27 10:00:00
...
2019-06-24 21:00:00-10:00   2019-06-25 07:00:00
```

And the output, `result['monthly_totals']` should look like:

```
time
2018-06-27 00:00:00-10:00      NaN
...
2019-06-24 20:00:00-10:00      720
2019-06-24 21:00:00-10:00      720
```

Again, my solution works, but the call to `apply` seems to make it hella slow. So I really want some help getting towards a cleaner solution that ditches that. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but can you provide a sample of your input (preferably code to construct a sample IntervalIndex) and expected output. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I edited in a function called `get_mock_montly_totals` to return a sample IntervalIndex. The expected output remains the same (`result['monthly_totals']`)

Comment: This should get you started: `idx = get_mock_montly_totals(); pd.IntervalIndex(idx.index).get_indexer(pd.to_datetime(hours.values))`

Comment: thanks! the get_indexer function was exactly what I needed to know about. ultimately, I did the following to make my code much less complex, and less than 1/3 the runtime:
`indexer = monthly_totals.index.get_indexer(hours); result['monthly_totals'] = np.take(monthly_totals.values, indexer)`